# Is there any algorithm that is O(n) time and necessarily uses O(n) auxiliary space?

Tags: algorithm

I have noticed that problems that can be solved in linear time can be tweaked to use no more than O(1) auxiliary space. Take Weighted Indepented Set problem for path graphs. If only total weight is required, it takes O(1) space. But if set is also asked for in solution, then it uses O(n) space, however, auxiliary space used is still O(1). Other problems that admit linear time algorithms are Maximum Subarray Sum problem, rotating a 1D vector by i positions, convert a BST to a sorted doubly linked list, etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Z algorithm](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2011/cmsc858s/Lec02-zalg.pdf), [linear-time suffix array generation](http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/wiki/pub/ABI/AdvancedAlgorithms11_Indices/script-08-SuffixArrayLinearTime.pdf), the [Burrows-Wheeler Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform), etc. all need O(n) auxiliary space.

Actually, I think even depth-first search, breadth-first search, etc. require O(n) auxiliary space in their worst cases (linked list for DFS, single-layer tree for BFS).

Comment: Oh yeah! DFS, BFS is a straightforward answer. I should have thought it. Well thanks, this was my first question in SO.

Comment: DFS, BFS: it depends on how you store your tree. E.g. DFS of a tree in which each node has links to both its parent and its children needs only O(1) aux. space.

Comment: btw Mehrdad, recently I have been having interest in algorithms and have pretty much covered decent stuff in Cormen and Klienberg. Can you suggest any book which covers these ones like Burrows-Wheeler and suffix array generation. You have given links and thanks for that but I would prefer some book.

Comment: @jods: Can you elaborate?  The only way I think that could work would be if, when you finish processing a node and go back "up" to its parent to finish processing any other children of the parent, you scan through each child of that parent to find the one you have just finished processing...  I think this will be O(n^2) in the worst case, where the graph is a clique.  (But if the degree of the graph is bounded by a constant k, then it will still be O(kn) = O(n).)

Comment: @Mehrdad: actually, I'm starting to think that depending on the tree the algo may not be O(n) in time anymore... But it's an important truth anyway that the data structure has an impact on both time and space complexity of algorithms.

Comment: @jods, yes but there is atleast one problem, like one in which one child doesn't have link to parent, which takes up O(n) space in worst case and that answers the question.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: the same thought just occured to me. Indeed for the algorithm to stay O(n) in time finding the next sibling requires O(1) time. So it depends on the datastructure... Several structures also store the next sibling in addition to parent and children and in those case it would be true. Storing the next sibling should also make BFS O(1) in space.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, jods: It is possible to make BFS constant space if each node "knows" where its next sibling is (perhaps by having a parent pointer and an index of where it is located, so that you can increment the index).

Comment: @user2436425: [Here's](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Strings-Trees-Sequences-Computational/dp/0521585198) one: *"Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences: Computer Science and Computational Biology"* by Dan Gusfield.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Hmmm, I agree with that, but if we're allowed to add n per-node counters "for free", how is that really different from a recursion stack of counters that never grows past size n?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: It's assumed to be already part of the input data structure and it's read-only, so N threads can use it simultaneously since it's a read-only operation; the amount of space doesn't depend on N. A recursion stack is dynamically allocated and modified, so if N threads want to make them in parallel, they have to dynamically allocate N times the memory. So actually pre-storing that information in the input is better, it allows for O(n) space rather than O(nN) space.

Comment: @user2436425: that's true, but choosing the best data structure is key to efficient algorithms. Given a choice I would implement what is most efficient in my situation. Other (now erased) answers said reversing a linked-list. To which it was said that by XOR the next pointer it didn't need extra storage, which is equivalent to saying that the list is doubly-linked...

Comment: @j_random_hacker: depends on your use case. Having a next sibling pointers is not uncommon, each node is still of constant size and traversal can be very efficient. If the cost of dynamically allocating auxilliary space is considered high (e.g. the algo. is run very often, or in parallell, or needs no allocations for real-time constraints, etc.) then 4 extra bytes per node could be a good choice.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ah, I see how the read-only next-sibling pointer would work now.  I think this would work with no "extra" space at all, since you could then do away with an array of pointers from the parent to each of its children, and give each parent just a pointer to its first child.  But I'm confused as to what you mean by "a parent pointer and an index of where it is located, so that you can increment the index" -- could you explain a bit more?  Thanks.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I meant that if every node knows it is the K'th child of its parent, then you can simply look at the parent for its (K + 1)'th child in constant time -- you don't *directly* need to know who the sibling is per se; knowing K (and who the parent is) is enough.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think the points about DFS and BFS can be summarized pretty simply: the algorithms requires O(N) data -- but in some cases, that data may already be available/stored, in which case you don't need *extra* storage for them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That's true for anything right? If what you need is already there then you obviously have less work to do.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It seems fairly obvious, but we still have a string of 15-20 comments basically saying little more than: "if the data's available, you won't have to compute it."

Comment: @JerryCoffin: What I was saying wasn't so trivial though. Read my comment about threading, I was making a different point than that. It's not an issue of whether it's already computed or whether you have to recompute it, it's an issue of *how much* each one will cost in terms of space. Precomputing can actually be more efficient for parallel processing.